# How to submit a Windows 7 bug?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm pretty sure I found a bug in Win7 64bit, how do I submit it to Microsoft?

Comment: May I ask what you've found?

Comment: This is probably a bug: http://j.mp/97fQdE

Answer (score 2):

Use http://connect.microsoft.com/ to submit bugs (actually from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175389/how-do-i-submit-a-bug-to-microsoft) SO question)

Edit: Not sure whether this works on windows 7(haven't tested)

- Start -> Run and type `rundll32.exe FeedbackTool.dll, ShowWizard`
- `Send an issue report` application will open. Just enter your Windows Live ID and send the feedback/bugs ( from [here](http://www.blogsdna.com/3349/how-to-report-bugs-send-feedback-in-windows-7-rc.htm) )

Comment: More help http://connect.microsoft.com/onecare/content/content.aspx?ContentID=3480

Comment: I can't see a section for Windows 7...

Comment: There isn't a section for Windows bug reports on MSFT Connect. It's perfect! ;)

Comment: Please note that bugs can no longer be submitted that way, the proper way is to contact the Customer Support. They can either help you fix the bug or otherwise forward it to the developers.