# How to report Windows 8 bug to Microsoft

Tags: windows

I recently (5 minutes ago) found a bug in my Windows 8 installation.

How can I report it to Microsoft?

Comment: Microsoft is not interested, therefore you can't report a Windows 7 or Windows 8 bug to Microsoft

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to suggest improvements for MS Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/526773/how-to-suggest-improvements-for-ms-windows-8), http://superuser.com/questions/67131, http://superuser.com/questions/612925, http://superuser.com/questions/149681

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You report it to the [Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us)

[source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/windows-8-where-to-report-bugs/b8073c35-6e0e-4089-bd48-0302357ea952)